# SQLAlchemy, query Uuid column as str in coalesce

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have following query operation, which includes a Uuid column(sqlalchemy.Uuid) of a model. I need to convert it to a string and use in coalesce.

```
session
  .query(
    ...
    coalesce(MyModel.id, "").label(...)
    ...)
  .join(...)
```

I used `str` and function, but it didn't work.
I want to get similar affect with `COALESCE(my_models.id::text, '')`. Is this possible with sqlalchemy query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in `coalesce` must be of the same or related types.  UUID and varchar / text are not sufficiently related, so we need to *cast* from UUID to text. The SQL could be

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(id, text), '') FROM tbl
```

or

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(id::text, '') FROM tbl
```

SQLAlchemy provides a [cast](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast) function for this. Your query would be:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
session.query(sa.func.coalesece(sa.cast(MyModel.id, sa.Text), '')...)
```

or in 2.0 style:

```py
sa.select(sa.func.coalesece(sa.cast(MyModel.id, sa.Text), '')...)
```